Azure container apps and azure application gateway integration - Which ports are actually used?
So I have integrated my application gateway with azure container apps.
I have the following ports exposed in my container app:

8080
5000
9000

I have the following nsg rule:
security_rule {
    name                         = "AllowInboundFromAGW"
    priority                     = 100
    direction                    = "Inbound"
    access                       = "Allow"
    protocol                     = "Tcp"
    source_port_range            = "*"
    destination_port_range      = "*" #[80, 443, 8080, 9000, 5000]
    source_address_prefixes      = var.public-subnet.address_prefixes
    destination_address_prefixes = var.private-subnet.address_prefixes
}

The following NSG rule is relatively permissive, thus i want to limit the access to the specific ports that agw use to talk with the container app.
I tried opening only the ports mentioned above in the destination port range, but it disconnects the services and the health prope is failing. I figured that a lot of magic is going on in Azure container apps (I did create the exact same setup in ACI without any issues), so obviously some additional ports are used which to me doesn't seem apparent in the documentation.

Kindly share the Application Gateway health status screenshot by editing the questions.

For default probes if the backend http settings are configured for HTTPS, the probe uses HTTPS to test health of the backend servers.For example: You configure your application gateway to use backend servers A, B, and C to receive HTTP network traffic on port 80. The default health monitoring tests the three servers every 30 seconds for a healthy HTTP response with a 30-second-timeout for each request.  refer MS Doc for more details

I am aware of this. But the health probe fails even though the beforementioned backend ports (which i'm using) are open, and the service is unreachable - Thus, I would assume that ACA use different ports behind the scenes.. even though it seems unlikely.

If the application gateway backend is unhealthy, make sure to check the backend settings and configure them as shown in the picture below. Since the Container Apps are operating on port 443, ensure that the protocol is set to HTTPS and the port is set to 443. Also, set Override with new host name to Yes and select the first option.

Backend Pool configuration

Backend Health

Application Gateway

After configuring the backend settings with the correct configuration, I am able to access the container app from the application gateway frontend IP.

Refer: Azure Container Apps with Web Application Firewall on Application Gateway
