Application gateway path based routing giving error for a configured path
Have configured application gateway for azure container apps with two containers
and configured path based routing but it showing below error for url http://98.64.93.3/container2,
what is missing in configuration as container1 is routing correctly please help
it is giving below error

attached is the screen shot of configuration of path  based routing

I have changed the configuration again  , observation is if I change default pool to 4, the default gateway IP redirects correctly to container

however If hit /container4/ -> it gives error as follows looks like some additional configuration is missing as there is no issue in container image that I have used and also in backend health as it is showing green


Can you please share the backend health screenshot by editing the question?

backend health is showing green

What about backend protocol? For container apps, it should be https 443. check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78865987/azure-container-apps-and-azure-application-gateway-integration-which-ports-are/78870781#78870781

problem is not about any configuration it is about only path based routing since I have two containers one of the container is opening successfully when I use  http://98.64.93.3/container1 , other one is not that is having path as http://98.64.93.3/container2 ,so basically I want to configure multiple paths redirecting to different containers  in container app , and later point frontend to application using application gateway public IP

Check the appgateway access logs.

where to check logs ? I m seeing one option in left side but that is opening so many options which option to choose

Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway about appgateway access logs

@VenkatV can you check I have updated question

I have been able to resolve issue by giving "/" in Override backend path in backend settings

